# SPWeb approvers. Different users for each SPWeb in a site collection

Tags: spweb

I have created a custom site collection and in this site collection are multiple SPWeb news sites.

The news SPWebs are moderated by different groups of users. I want to create a group for each news web called 'News Owners' and in each web assign specific people who will be in charge of approving content for that web.
How do I achieve this? It seems that the sharepoint groups only apply to site collection scope and not to the individual webs.

I am using Nintex workflows in these webs which should send emails to the approvers of the web but I don't know how to achieve this.

Comment: You create the group for every web (they are indeed stored on the site collection level)
Then set the appropriate group as approvers in every subweb after breaking inheritance.

Comment: Is it possible to have the same name for each group? If I try and create a group with the same name in each web, Sharepoint throws an exception saying the group name already exists. The reason I ask is I want to use the same name for the group across all webs as I'm using it as a constant in my nintex workflow. From what you're saying I'd create a 'Japan News Approvers' group and a 'US News Approvers' group if I had a Japan news web and a US news web.

Comment: No, that's not possible, every group needs to be unique. That's why SharePoint includes the web name in the default groups. Maybe you can look for people/groups with Approval rights in you workflow?